# I have not found pretty print built in my Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've seen this tool in YouTube

[Chrome Dev Tools Reloaded](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg&feature=player_embedded)

[image]

But I have not found in my Chrome dev tools ,, What is the reason?

[image]

thanks

Comment: I came to this question despite using a modern version of chrome, because the pretty-print option only shows when the console is hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the latest dev-channel version of Chrome?  I believe this feature was added first to v13, so if you're running the stable or beta versions, you won't have access to the feature.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome 12 has a "De-obfuscate Source” feature on the right-click context menu under Scripts. It seems to do the same thing as the Pretty Print button in Chrome 13.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Chrome 16, and the current behavior is exactly as the OP's original screen shot shows.  In other words, there should be a curly braces "{}" button on the bottom of the script tab labeled "Pretty Print".

(I'm posting this answer since I was confused looking for a "De-obfuscate Source" popup menu item)